# Not able to fetch mobile numbers in j2me

Tags: java-me, pim

When I tried to fetch phonebook contacts using:

```
contactInfo.mobileNo = contactItem.getString(Contact.TEL,0);
```

I only get numbers under **Phone number** entry, and not showing entries under **Mobile number**.

How to fetch Phonebook entry under Mobile number?

Answer (score 3):

You are only fetching one element, need to loop

**contactItem.getString(Contact.TEL,0);**

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.*;
import javax.microedition.pim.Contact;
import javax.microedition.pim.ContactList;
import javax.microedition.pim.PIM;

String str = "";
try {
    PIM pim = PIM.getInstance();
    String[] names = pim.listPIMLists(PIM.CONTACT_LIST);
    pim.openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY, names[0]);
    ContactList addressbook = (ContactList) (pim.openPIMList(PIM.CONTACT_LIST, PIM.READ_ONLY));
    Contact contact = null;
    String phoneNumber = null;
    Enumeration items = null;
    items = addressbook.items();
    while (items.hasMoreElements()) {
        contact = (Contact) items.nextElement();
        int telCount = contact.countValues(Contact.TEL);
        int nameCount = contact.countValues(Contact.FORMATTED_NAME);

        if (telCount > 0 && nameCount > 0) {

            String contactName = contact.getString(Contact.FORMATTED_NAME, 0);
            System.out.println("\n\nName: "+contactName);
            str += "\n\nName: "+contactName;
            for (int i = 0; i < telCount; i++) {
                phoneNumber = contact.getString(Contact.TEL, i);
                System.out.println("\nNumber: "+phoneNumber);
                str += "\nNumber: "+phoneNumber;
            }
        }
    }
} catch (SecurityException e) {
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, I am trying this, and let you know........Thanks a lot...

Comment: I have applied the same code, but still not fetching all contacts.......Any other suggestions.....

Comment: @chetan I have just checked the code on my device, its working. I have simplified it. Check if you are getting any exception?